# What are all the possible tabs that can be opened in the QGIS log window

Tags: qgis, log

Sometimes, when opening a QGIS project, certain tabs open in the log panel. Here are two different examples:

1:
[image]

2:
[image]

I'm just wondering: what are *all the possible tabs* - apart from those for user installed extensions - that can open down there?

I'm basically asking that because I'm not able to figure out where I can open back some of the tabs which were manually closed.

Comment: You'd basically have to scoure the sources for QgsMessageLog.logMessage and look at the second parameter `level`: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.32/core/QgsMessageLog.html#qgis.core.QgsMessageLog.logMessage . E. g. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aqgis%2FQGIS%20logmessage&type=code . This won't be fun because they can be localized strings. It would be a great feature request to harmonize this and to have some way to re-open tabs that had log message during a running QGIS session.